# Selecting minimum value using a subquery

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

I need to write a query to grab the lowest price from each merchant and output the price link (p_link) and some other information such as merchant name + rating.

We have a table for prices (tgmp_prices), a table for merchants (tgmp_merchants) and a table for affiliate product ids (tgmp_affiliates)

I have already got the query to grab all of the prices and data that I need:

```
SELECT p_id, p_m_id, p_prod_label, a_platform, p_link, p_price, m_title, m_link, m_avg_rating 
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga 
JOIN tgmp_prices p 
    ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin 
        AND ga.a_code != '' 
JOIN tgmp_merchants m 
    ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id 
WHERE ga.site_id = '34' 
    AND p.site_id = '34' 
    AND ga.a_parent = '25573' 
    AND p_type = 'games' 
    AND m.m_hide = 0 
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```

I just need to group the prices by merchant id (p.p_m_id or m.m_id) and select the lowest price for each merchant.

```
SELECT p_id, p_m_id, p_prod_label, a_platform, p_link, p_price, m_title, m_link, m_avg_rating 
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga 
JOIN tgmp_prices p 
    ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin 
        AND ga.a_code != '' 
JOIN tgmp_merchants m 
    ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id 
WHERE ga.site_id = '34' 
    AND p.site_id = '34' 
    AND ga.a_parent = '25573' 
    AND p_type = 'games' 
    AND m.m_hide = 0 
GROUP BY m.m_id
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```

If I add GROUP BY m.m_id before ORDER BY I get 16 results, 1 for each merchant. I just need to make this the lowest price. So I tried adding a sub query where the prices table (tgmp_prices) is joined as so:

```
SELECT p_id, p_m_id, p_prod_label, a_platform, p_link, p_price, m_title, m_link, m_avg_rating 
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga 
JOIN tgmp_prices p 
    ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin 
        AND ga.a_code != '' 
        AND p.p_price = ( 
            SELECT MIN(p.p_price) 
            FROM tgmp_prices 
            WHERE p.p_m_id = m.m_id
        ) 
JOIN tgmp_merchants m 
    ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id 
WHERE ga.site_id = '34' 
    AND p.site_id = '34' 
    AND ga.a_parent = '25573' 
    AND p_type = 'games' 
    AND m.m_hide = 0 
GROUP BY m.m_id
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```

This doesn't give me the correct results - I think the issue could possibly be that m.m_id isn't available when the sub query is run, so I've tried joining the merchants table within the sub query but I still end up with the same set of results.

DDL as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tgmp_affiliates` (
    `a_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `a_parent` int(8) NOT NULL,
    `a_code` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `a_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `a_platform` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`a_parent`,`a_code`,`a_type`,`a_platform`),
    KEY `a_code` (`a_code`),
    KEY `a_parent` (`a_parent`),
    KEY `a_platform` (`a_platform`),
    KEY `a_type` (`a_type`),
    KEY `site_id_2` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tgmp_merchants`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tgmp_merchants` (
    `m_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `m_title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `m_url` text NOT NULL,
    `m_link` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `m_favicon` text NOT NULL,
    `m_avg_rating` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `m_hide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`m_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `m_title` (`m_title`,`m_link`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tgmp_prices`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tgmp_prices` (
    `p_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
    `p_m_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
    `p_prod_label` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `p_gtin` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `p_parent` int(8) NOT NULL,
    `p_link` text NOT NULL,
    `p_price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `p_delivery` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `p_currencey` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `p_avail` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `p_condition` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `p_when` datetime NOT NULL,
    `p_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `p_hide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`p_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `p_gtin` (`p_gtin`,`p_m_id`,`p_price`,`p_delivery`),
    KEY `p_price` (`p_price`),
    KEY `p_parent` (`p_parent`),
    KEY `site_id` (`site_id`),
    KEY `p_gtin_2` (`p_gtin`),
    KEY `p_type` (`p_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

I have now amended the query to the following:

```
SELECT p_id, p_m_id, p_prod_label, a_platform, p_link, p_price, m_title, m_link, m_avg_rating 
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga 
JOIN tgmp_prices p 
    ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin 
        AND ga.a_code != '' 
        AND p.p_price = (
            SELECT MIN(tp.p_price) FROM tgmp_prices tp
                WHERE tp.p_m_id = m.m_id
                AND tp.p_parent = '25573'
    )
JOIN tgmp_merchants m 
    ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id 
WHERE ga.site_id = '34' 
    AND p.site_id = '34' 
    AND ga.a_parent = '25573' 
    AND p_type = 'games' 
    AND m.m_hide = 0 
GROUP BY m.m_id
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```

This gives the correct number of results and they are very close to the correct set of results but I'm still not getting the lowest price for each merchant.

Comment: I think problem with SELECT MIN(p.p_price) 
            FROM tgmp_prices 
            WHERE p.p_m_id = m.m_id which always give same and true

Comment: try with SELECT MIN(tp.p_price) FROM tgmp_prices tp

Comment: It's useful to see your query because it demonstrates that you have at least tried to solve the problem yourself. But in order to help us to help you, you should really consider proper DDLs (and/or an SQLFIDDLE) for the above, including the desired and corresponding result set.

Comment: Did you try with HAVING ?

Comment: The mistake is in aliasing - subquery uses `p.` while it should use `tgmp_prices` in both p_price and p_m_id. As it is written now subquery should return p_price from outer query.

Comment: There is another filter you use in outer query but not in subquery: site_id. You need to replicate all conditions you apply in outer query to subquery. This might apply to joins also because inner join might remove rows.

Comment: But I think that you are not going at it the right way. [Here is an article about selecting top n rows per group](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104). `EntryDate` in example is price from your query, `id` is combination of columns you group by (p_parent, p_m_id, I don't know if there are more).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ?:

```
SELECT p_id,
       p_m_id,
       p_prod_label,
       a_platform,
       p_link,
       p_price,
       m_title,
       m_link,
       m_avg_rating
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga
JOIN tgmp_prices p ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin
AND ga.a_code != ''
JOIN tgmp_merchants m ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id
WHERE ga.site_id = '34'
  AND p.site_id = '34'
  AND ga.a_parent = '25573'
  AND p_type = 'games'
  AND m.m_hide = 0
  AND p.p_price = (SELECT MIN(p2.p_price) 
                   FROM tgmp_prices p2
                   WHERE p2.p_m_id = m.m_id)
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a subquery as a criterion instead of adding it as an additional source of records. Here's a tweak:

```
SELECT p_id, p_m_id, p_prod_label, a_platform
       , p_link, p_price, m_title, m_link, m_avg_rating, MinPrice
FROM tgmp_affiliates ga 
JOIN tgmp_prices p 
    ON ga.a_code = p.p_gtin 
        AND ga.a_code != ''
JOIN tgmp_merchants m 
    ON m.m_id = p.p_m_id 

JOIN
    (
        SELECT tp.p_m_id as lp_m_id, MIN(tp.p_price) AS MinPrice FROM tgmp_prices tp
            WHERE tp.p_parent = '25573'
            GROUP BY tp.p_m_id
    ) LowestPriceForEachMerchant
    ON m.m_id = LowestPriceForEachMerchant.lp_m_id

WHERE ga.site_id = '34' 
    AND p.site_id = '34' 
    AND ga.a_parent = '25573' 
    AND p_type = 'games' 
    AND m.m_hide = 0 
GROUP BY m.m_id
ORDER BY p.p_price ASC
```